# cython prange get error of pyeval_savethread: null tstate

Tags: python, cython

always get error of "pyeval_savethread: null tstate"

I tried to use cython to do some parallel computing by prange. But I found when I use the function which returns pointer, I will get the above error. I really don't have any idea how to deal with that.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double *jonswap(double *w, double Hs, double Tp, int n, double gamma = 3.7) nogil:
    '''
    Function to obtain Jonswap spectra
    w: wave frequency range [rad/s]
    '''
    cdef:
        double *sigma = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
        double *a = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
        double fhs = Hs * Hs
        double ftp = Tp * Tp * Tp * Tp
        double wp = 2 * M_PI / Tp
        Py_ssize_t i

    cdef double *sj = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))

    with nogil:
        for i in range(n):
            sigma[i] = 0.07 if w[i] < wp else 0.09
            a[i] = exp(-0.5 * pow((w[i] - wp) / (sigma[i] * w[i]), 2.0))
            sj[i] = 320 * fhs * pow(w[i], -5.0) / ftp * exp(-1950 * pow(w[i], -4) / ftp) * pow(gamma, a[i])



    free(sigma)
    free(a)

    return sj

def test():
    cdef:
        double dw = 0.05
        int n = 43
        int i = 0
        double *w = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
        double Hs = 3.0
        double Tp = 8.0

    for i in range(n):
        w[i] = 0.35 + i * dw

    # initialize Jonswap spectra and wave elevation
    cdef:
        double *S_wave
        int j
        double suma = 0.0
        # double[:] z = np.zeros((n), dtype=DTYPE_float)

    with nogil, parallel():
        S_wave = jonswap(w, Hs, Tp, n)
        for i in prange(100, schedule='guided'):            
            suma += sumw(S_wave,n)
        free(S_wave)

    return suma

cdef double sumw(double *s, int n) nogil:
    cdef:
        int i
        double suma = 0
    for i in range(n):
        suma += s[i]

    return suma
```

it is just a test. No error occurs when compiled. But when I run test function it get the error. I am wondering if anyone knows how this can be fixed. I'll really appreciate that.

Comment: You're releasing the GIL inside a function that you've already marked as `nogil`. I don't think that makes sense (you can't release what you don't have!). I'm not sure if that's your problem though

Comment: thank you David. I tried what you recommended. but still get the same error. I'd like to use the function which returns pointer inside the prange actually. I am not sure if the error is related to memory leak or something. the code I showed is not for test. I actually have make a function containing other functions that return pointer. and use that function into prange loop. that's where the error occurs. for those returning NONE pointers, prange works properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error _isn't_ related to returning pointers - that's fine at C level so won't need the gil. If it didn't go away when your remove the nogil block in jonswap then I really don't have any ideas

Comment: Can you make sure the code you show is complete though... We don't have definitions for exp, pow, malloc and free, and this might be important

Comment: Hi, David. I remove the with nogil, it still got the same error. But I found another way to solve the problem. I change the jonswap function to a void function which assigns the pointer inside the function. If the problem is not related to returning pointer, can you give an example of running pointer function inside a prange? I am just wondering if it works. because i tried running function which returns pointed inside the prange, it got the same error.

Comment: I've edited a working example returning `prange`. I'm not really sure why yours is different because your example isn't really complete. I wonder if some of the "C" functions you use like `malloc`, `free`, `pow`, etc aren't actually defined anywhere so it tries to look for a Python global with the same name (which requires the GIL). I really can't tell though, so I don't plan to look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

Since your example is incomplete I created a simpler one which confirms my initial thought that the problem is related to a `nogil` block inside a `nogil` function:

```
cdef int f(int x) nogil:
    cdef int y
    with nogil:
        y = x+1 # do some work without the GIL
    return x

def test():
    cdef int out
    with nogil:
        out = f(1)
```

Giving:

> Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate

The issue is either that with `with nogil` block inside `f` tries to release the GIL when you don't hold it, or it tries to regain it at the end of the block when it shouldn't do. The solution is to remove the unnecessary `with nogil:` block (in this case inside `f`, in your case inside `jonswap`)

Ideally Cython should probably flag this as an error.

---

**Edit:** a simplified test that shows you can return pointers in a parallel block without error. It doesn't do anything much useful.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

from cython.parallel import prange, parallel


def test():
    cdef:
        double *S_wave
        int i
        double suma = 0
        int n = 50

    with nogil, parallel():
        S_wave = allocate(n)
        for i in prange(100):
            suma += sumw(S_wave,n)
        free(S_wave)

    print(suma)

cdef double sumw(double *s, int n) nogil:
    cdef:
        int i
        double suma = 0
    for i in range(n):
        suma += s[i]

    return suma

cdef double* allocate(int n) nogil:
    cdef double* out = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double)*n)
    cdef int i
    for i in range(n):
        out[i] = i*0.5
    return out
```